# NSURLConnectionLoader signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios7, nsurlconnection, cllocationmanager, sigabrt, opentok

I am using `OpenTok` framework and it crashes like following:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x17a535b4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.
```

I have also enabled Zombie, Malloc guard, Malloc Stack and also scribble in Scheme setting of project. But i am not able to get exact line of code. I have also tried Intrument but it also fails to get exact error.

Can anyone help me out in this regards.?

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest [iOS version](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/) for OpenTok. The new version fixes some of the memory issues that previous versions are experiencing.